# Sum of series in matlab using symsum

Tags: matlab

I have the following series

[image]

I tried this code but it does not print the final result...instead gives a long line of numbers!

```
syms n
y = symsum(1/sqrt(n),[1,100])
```

Result:

```
y =

2^(1/2)/2 + 3^(1/2)/3 + 5^(1/2)/5 + 6^(1/2)/6 + % and so on....
```

So the question is how to produce a final number as answer?!

Should I go with a script like this instead?

```
y = 0;
for i = 1:1:100
    y = y + (1/sqrt(i));
end
disp(y);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about dropping the loop and use this instead:

```
n=1:100
result = sum(1./sqrt(n))

>> result =

   18.5896
```

I'm not sure if you want to use the symbolic sum of series function in your case since you are only dealing with a simple function.

Comment: Sorry I am a noob...what is that `./` for? what does it do

Comment: the ./ stands for dot divide, in matlab when you want a Dot operation, you just add the dot in-front and matlab knows that you want to do the element wise (dot) operation. so you can use .* (dot product) for example. It's really good for speed/efficiency when you are in vector/matrix space.

Comment: @GameOfThrows It isn't really the dot product, is it...? The [Dot product](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dot.html) is different from the [Element-wise multiplication](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/times.html). Given this: `A = [4 -1 2]; B = [2 -2 -1];`, `A.*B` is ***not*** equal to `dot(A,B)`

Comment: @kkuilla you are right, it is dot multiply. too late to make corrections.

Answer (score 6):

To answer the original question, you can convert the symbolic expression you initially got using [double](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/double.html), to convert from a symbolic to a numeric value:

```
y = double(y)
```

Or actually:

```
syms n
y = double(symsum(1/sqrt(n),[1,100]))
```

and you get 18.5896.

Additionally, you can use [eval](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html?searchHighlight=eval) to evaluate the symbolic expression (thanks Luis Mendo).

Yay!

Comment: Also `eval(y)` works. `sym/eval` evaluates a symbolic expression

Comment: right I'll add it to the answer if you don't mind :)

Comment: @LuisMendo Isn't `eval` bad...?

Comment: @kkuilla But this is not the standard `eval` (execute a string; not recommended because it obfuscates code). This is `sym/eval`, that is, `eval` applied on a sym variable, which computes its the numeric value